# Windows Batch - Find image files inside folders that have a certain name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a windows batch script which can select all `.bmp` files within directories named beginning with a certain string.

Example of the directory structure:

```
c:\root
 |- images
     |- 2020-08-19
         |- 001-ABC
         |   |- firstfile.bmp
         |   |- secondfile.bmp
         |
         |- 002-DEF
             |- thirdfile.bmp
             |- fourthfile.bmp
```

I would like to be able to execute a command (in this case: convert to JPG) on all `.bmp` files inside folders which are named beginning with `001-`

So, in the above example, the following files would be selected for execution:

```
c:\root\images\2020-08-10\001-ABC\firstfile.bmp
c:\root\images\2020-08-10\001-ABC\secondfile.bmp
```

I was able to find the desired folders but could not figure out how to do the rest:

```
forfiles /P c:\root\images /S /M 001-*
```

How can I find all `.bmp` files within these folders and then execute the conversion?
(note: I already know the execution command)

Comment: Where are you intending to locate your batch file? `ForFiles` is probably not the best for your specific task, you'd need to limit your commands `/C`, first to, `If @ISDir==TRUE`, then you'd need to create a nested loop to cycle through each of the files within those. I would advise that you use stick with [tag:for-loop]'s instead. Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read all of the information presented. Please also note that probably half of all answers under the [batch-file] tag use these loops, there will certainly be plenty of examples to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

For example, use an outer [for /d](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) loop to iterate all needed folders, and use an inner [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) loop to iterate `.bmp` files:

```
@echo off

set "_root_=c:\root\images\2020-08-10"
set "_prefix_=001-"

for /d %%A in ("%_root_%\%_prefix_%*") do (
  for %%B in ("%%A\*.bmp") do (
    echo processing '%%B'...
  )
)
```

Update.

Or the same as one-liner:

```
forfiles /p "c:\root\images\2020-08-10" /m "001-*" /s /c "cmd /c @for %A in ("@path\*.bmp") do @echo processing '%A'..."
```

Comment: Dmitry, I would still encourage you to use `if @isdir==TRUE` to exclude the possibility of picking up filenames beginning with `001-`. I would also possibly check whether the `/s` option is required from that particular `/p` path, it would be more likely from `c:\root\images`, but unclear given the information provided.

Comment: Using FORFILES is massively inefficient if there are many iterations to process because you are opening a new instance of cmd.exe for each iteration of the `FORFILES` output.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "dirprefix=001-"
SET "datestring=2020-08-19"
FOR /f "tokens=*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.bmp" ^|find /i "%sourcedir%\%datestring%\%dirprefix%"'
 ) DO (
ECHO process "%%~a"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

Processing is: Perform a `dir` listing subdirectories of all '.bmp' files in basic form (which lists all of the required files in absolute format), then filter for the required strings using `for` and make the filter case-insensitive using `/i`.

Then process the resulting list using `for/f` with `delims=` to assign the entire line to `%%a`.